# getting cookie from an external javascript in php before generating HTML output

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

Is it possible getting cookie from an external js with Php before generating HTML to the browser?

Something like

```
 <?

     //Get if i have some cookie information
     if($_COOKIE["js_app"])
           $cookie_js = $_COOKIE["js_app"];

     //now, talk with some app.js
     if($cookie_js)
         $cookie = some_function(target = 'some_domanin/app.js',$cookie_js);
     else
         $cookie = some_function(target = 'some_domanin/app.js');

     $_COOKIE["js_app"] = $cookie;

     //now i can generate the HTML output. 

    ....


  ?>
```

Comment: Javascript sets cookies within the browser. With each new request, the browser will pass the cookie to the server, so PHP can read it. However, your code calls some JS directly (how?) and is not a browser so I wonder what you're looking for.

Comment: @hakre Of course, I know is it very strange and I don't know how. I was wondering if was possible loading javascript in some way with php.

Comment: You want to execute javascript code within PHP code?

Comment: If executing javascript is the only way to get the cookie information yes, otherwise no.

Comment: Please add the code of the PHP function `some_function` to your question. Please add the javascript code that sets the cookie to your question. Then: What have you done so far? What exactly is your problem? What do you expect? You might be misunderstanding the technologies you're making use of and how they work together so you should provide more details so that folks here can actually help you.

Comment: I have no `some_function`. I have no problem.  Simply i'm looking for a way (it is not sure it exists) for getting cookie information from an external js with Php. `some_function` is exactly the way i'm searching for. I'm non misundertanding technoligies, I know the way they work togheter and I know the difficulties. I know this is a little "dream". :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible because the javascript would never be executed. Your `some_function` (assuming it used cURL to make the request and pass along the cookie), would just receive the javascript code (like what happens when you view javascript source in your browser).

When JS is loaded by the browser, the browser's javascript interpreter handles parsing and executing the javascript.

**Edit:** Hmm... googling for "php javascript interpreter" resulted in http://j4p5.sourceforge.net/index.php. Never used it before and probably never will but if you don't need to interact with the user-side of things, that might help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a way to send request with cookies, and get the cookies from the response using PHP, right? I think [PEAR HTTP_Request](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-request.cookie.php) is what you are looking for, although you have to install it on your server as a package.

If that is not an option, I guess you will have to do [HTTP requests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http) using [sockets](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php).

**UPDATE**: If you are setting the cookies using Javascript, you will have to parse the javascript - not really an option. These functions only work when the cookies are set server-side.

Comment: I need not setting cookie using javascript. I need only get cookie information and (in case) get some return value. Only that. Not execution. - **UPDATE**: _return value_ is impossible.